# Django 'No module named 'suit.apps' error

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to customize Django admin site. I ran the command **"pip install django-suit"**, everything installed correctly according to CMD, then I made a new .py file called with apps.py in the main folder(same folder that contains settings.py) and here is the code

```
from suit.apps import DjangoSuitConfig

class SuitConfig(DjangoSuitConfig):
    layout = 'horizontal'
```

and added  `'database.apps.SuitConfig',`in the settings.py. When I type the command **"python manage.py makemigrations database"** or **"python manage.py runserver"** the CMD gives me this error

[image]

Does anyone know what am I missing?

My Django version = 2.0.7

Comment: Did you do `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: @argo yep, just tried it, still giving me no module named 'suit.apps' error

Answer (score 1):

If you installed django-suit using `pip install django-suit`, you installed v0.2.26, and then this whole installation you're doing is wrong. This is how to install in your Django project: [Getting started docs](https://django-suit.readthedocs.io/en/develop/getting_started.html). Note that v0.2.26 does introduce support for Django 2.0 so it should work.

If you want to use the v2 (which is not stable and currently still just a development branch), you should use a different source for `pip install`:

```
pip uninstall django-suit
pip install https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tarball/v2
```

Then you can do as you mention in your question, by subclassing `DjangoSuitConfig` and adding the new class to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I followed your and the docs instructions, but now is giving me a different error. I edited the question

Comment: Always check compatibility of packages before using them. Django-suit doesn’t support Django 2 yet, it supports up to Django 1.11. And `urlresolvers` part has changed. So maybe you should try the v2 dev version after all.

Comment: is the installation that i originally followed was intended for the v2 dev version?

Comment: Yes. Subclassing `DjangoSuitConfig` is the new way to customize the configuration in v2 of django-suit.

Comment: I was wrong when I mentioned v0.2.26 didnt' support Django 2.0. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, if you installed v 0.2.26.